# Mysql syntax seems to be correct but gives error code 1064

Tags: php, mysql

My error gives 1064 it worked before i inserted the where statement. Do i put the where before or after the from?

```
<?PHP
session_start();

include ("connection.php");

$city = $_POST['city'];

$state = $_POST['state'];

$results = array();
if( $query =  $db->query("SELECT business_id, BusinessName, date, post ".
  "FROM WolfeboroC.posts ". "WHERE city= '$city' && state='$state'".
  "JOIN WolfeboroC.users ON users.recid = posts.business_id ".
  "ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 0, 500") ) 
{
  while($record = $query->fetch_assoc())
  {
    $results[] = $record;
  }
  $query->close();
}

echo json_encode($results);
?>
```

Comment: Change your `&&` to `AND`

Comment: oh right i was in php think mode thanks

Comment: It happens, no harm done.

Comment: how come it doesn't run in mysql database it doesn't like the join command

Comment: Probably  because it's set inside double quotes. Commands should be by themselves, to a certain extent. That's what I tend to think is happening.

Comment: i didn't put them in quotes when i put it into the editor just running the script 

SELECT business_id, BusinessName, date, post
FROM WolfeboroC.posts WHERE city= 'beverly' AND state = 'MA'
JOIN WolfeboroC.users ON users.recid = posts.business_id
ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 0, 500;

Comment: If it works in your editor, then apply it the same way, yet enclosed in double quotes just before your `SELECT` and at the end of your line. Why do you have concatenates and double quotes inside it?

Comment: it might be helpful to mention that i have a table with users and a column called BusinessName that has all the business' names. Then i have a table that has posts. The join is combining Business Name from users with the table posts

Comment: it didn't work in the editor i think it isn't finding the column Business name

Answer (score 1):

```
"SELECT business_id, BusinessName, date, post ".
"FROM WolfeboroC.posts ". "WHERE city= '$city' && state='$state'".
"JOIN WolfeboroC.users ON users.recid = posts.business_id ".
"ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 0, 500"
```

SHOULD BE

```
"SELECT business_id, BusinessName, date, post ".
"FROM WolfeboroC.posts ". 
"JOIN WolfeboroC.users ON users.recid = posts.business_id ".
"WHERE city= '$city' AND state='$state'".
"ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 0, 500"
```

The JOIN verb should come before WHERE.

Comment: Error Code: 1052. Column 'city' in where clause is ambiguous

Comment: and by the way Fred ii had it right the && should be AND. thats a problem but doesn't fix it

Comment: Change WHERE city=  to  WHERE  tablename.city=  where "tablename" is the table that you are using to check the city from.

Comment: So it would be either WHERE posts.city=  or users.city=

Answer (score 0):

Your `JOIN WolfeboroC.users` syntax is not having space before it, so it is going wrong to `MySQL`.

Your code:

```
if( $query =  $db->query("SELECT business_id, BusinessName, date, post ".
  "FROM WolfeboroC.posts ". "WHERE city= '$city' && state='$state'".
  "JOIN WolfeboroC.users ON users.recid = posts.business_id ".
  "ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 0, 500") )
```

Corrected Code:

```
if( $query =  $db->query("SELECT business_id, BusinessName, date, post ".
  "FROM WolfeboroC.posts "." JOIN WolfeboroC.users ON users.recid = posts.business_id
```

WHERE city= '$city' && state='$state'
".
      "ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 0, 500") )

Also, you are selecting fields: `business_id, BusinessName, date, post`.

These fields are ambigious.

You are joining two tables.

Hence you should specify, which field comes from which Table.

e.g. `users.business_id, users.BusinessName, posts.date, posts.post`

Here, `MySQL` has to guess which field is of which table.

If a field exists for both the tables, it should throw an error.

Also, in the SQL, `WolfeboroC.users`

You should not specify the database name.

It should be `users' only.

As database name is configurable for most of the sites, it will change.